# Image processing books Gonzalez et al. vs Sonka et al?

Tags: image-processing, reference-request

I don't know where else to post this question so here it goes. I'm trying to buy a DIP book and the best two right now are:

- Image Processing, Analysis, and Machine Vision by Roger Boyle, Milan Sonka, Vaclav Hlavac 4th ed.
- Digital Image Processing by Rafael C. Gonzalez, Richard E. Woods 4th ed.

They're both pricey books. So if anyone has read these books and can make a recommendation or a pros/cons comparisons of the books, I'd appreciate it.

I've already bought the "Digital Signal Processing: A Practical Guide for Engineers and Scientists by Steven W. Smith".

Comment: Are you enrolled at a university?

Comment: also, third edition of Gonzalez costs like $5 used. Might be worth buying to test whether the fourth would be worth it. The fourth edition [seems to be $13](https://www.abebooks.com/products/isbn/9789353062989?cm_sp=bdp-_-ISBN10-_-PLP). That's literally the cheapest textbook I've ever heard of.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am in Europe so used English textbooks are hard to come by, also not enrolled in any Uni.

Comment: I'm in Europe myself. Many of these offers ship worldwide. The Uni question was because many, if not most, university libraries are open to the public (you can't take books with you, though), and it'd be useful to just go to one and check the books out.

Comment: Are there specific topics you want to learn? There are many good "open source" books as well

Comment: @LaurentDuval, Could you list them?

Comment: @LaurentDuval After bachelors I've worked for a couple of years in computer vision field but my fundamentals are not strong, hence I bought the DSP book and now I want a good DIP book. I am trying to make a strong mathematical foundation of these subjects.

Comment: Some pdf versions of books can be found online (for good reasons or not). For instance the 3rd edition of Gonzalez and Woods is here http://sdeuoc.ac.in/sites/default/files/sde_videos/Digital%20Image%20Processing%203rd%20ed.%20-%20R.%20Gonzalez%2C%20R.%20Woods-ilovepdf-compressed.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there are "best" image processing or computer vision books to buy. The topics covered can be very wide, and some can be better on some aspect (morphology, segmentation, denoising, etc.).

Some sites recommend a hanful of such books, and link to their draft versions, as in [8 Books for Getting Started With Computer Vision](https://machinelearningmastery.com/computer-vision-books/). Indeed, a lot of authors have a draft on a personal page. This is the case for instance for [Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf) by [Richard Szeliski](http://szeliski.org/Book/).

[CVonline: Vision Related Books including Online Books and Book Support Sites](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/books.htm) also points to classics, like:

- D. H. Ballard, C. M. Brown; [Computer Vision](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/BANDB/bandb.htm), Prentice-Hall Inc New Jersey, 1982, ISBN 0-13-165316-4.
- A. Blake, M. Isard; [Active contours](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~contours/), Springer, London, 1998, ISBN 3540762175.

Comment: I've skimmed the Szeliski book but I feel it's more of a next step after the DIP book. I am trying to get a good mathematical foundation of DSP and DIP which will help in the next step, which is the CV book by Szeliski and ESL by Tibshirani.